# Passing lambdas with different signatures to generic function

Tags: c++, c++11

Considering the following toy example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(T func, int *i) {
    if (i) {
        func(*i);
    } else {
        func();
    }
}

int main() {
    auto n = new int{2};
    foo([](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }, n);
    foo([]() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }, nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a function which receives lambdas functions with different signatures and call them inside its scope. If I do not call the lambda function inside `foo`, it compiles fine, but if I call it, the code does not compile.

Is there any way of receiving lambdas with different signatures and call it in a function?

Comment: `T` is determined at compile time. It cannot magically vary at run time. What's the ultimate point of this exercise? Looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wanna implement a BFS method where there are many different implementations of the visit() function. Until now, there are 2 different signatures for visit() (but many different implementations)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show an example?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It would take a long time making a minimal example for the BFS case... Maybe I can explain better: I want to pass visit() as a BFS argument, because I have many implementations of visit()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your function template, `T` has to be determined as one specific type, and remains that type throughout the entirety of that instantiation.

You can, however, accomplish what you want by making `foo` a variadic template, and passing the parameter pack through to the lambda that was passed in:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void foo(T func, Args... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto n = new int{ 2 };
    foo([](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }, n[0]);
    foo([]() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; });
    foo([](int a, int b) { std::cout << a + b << "\n"; }, 3, 2);
}
```

This way `foo` only needs to contain one invocation of `func`, which has a consistent type throughout each instantiation--but can vary from one instantiation to the next.

In this case, when the function you're passing doesn't take any arguments, you don't pass a special value for the argument. If it doesn't take an argument, you just don't pass an argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @aaamourao this allows static approach, but if type of function changes during real time, you would need to use some function object different from lambda or function pointer and allows type erasure

Answer (score 1):

In the first case where you instantiate the template function with:

```
foo([](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }, n);
```

The compiler creates the function where (T func) is a callable taking an int as function, therefore you can't do:

```
void foo(T func, int *i) {
    if (i) {
        func(*i);
    }
    //else 
    //{
    //  func(); // Can't call T func with no argument.
    //} // Commenting this out will compile.
}
```

When you instantiate the template function with:

```
foo([]() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }, nullptr);
```

The compiler creates the function:

```
void foo(T func, int *i); // Where T func is a callable taking no arguments
```

So, in contrast to the previous example, you must must call T func with no arguments given. Therefore you can't do:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T func, int *i) 
{
    //if (i) {
    //  func(*i); // Can't call T func with one argument, because 
                  // T func function template has been instantiated 
                  // as T func taking no arguments.
    //}
    //else 
    {
        func(); // This obviously is fine.
    }
}
```